# factorial proof using induction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

could someone check my answer to see if its correct or if i missed something. Thank you.

Problem: $2^n < (n+1)!$ for all integers $n \ge 2$ (Use Induction)

Base Case: Show that $n = 2$ is true $2^2 < (2+1)!$ = $4<6$

Hypothesis: Assume that $  2^k<(k+1)!$ is true for some int $k$ in $n$ and $k \ge 2$

Inductive step: Show that $n=k+1$ is also true \begin{align}2^{k+1} &=2^k \cdot 2^1\\&<(k+1)!2\\&<(k+2)(k+1)!\\ 2^{k+1}&<[(k+1)+1]! \end{align}
Since the statement is true for $n=2$ and true for $n=k$, means that $n=k+1$ is also true and the statement is also true for all $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fine.

My minor comment is that you might want to make things clearer.

- $2^2 < (2+1)! \color{red}= 4<6$

You want to write it at a different line. 
$$2^2 < (2+1)!$$
$$\iff 4< 6$$

- write "$k$ in $n$" as $k \in \mathbb{N}$.