# How do I use induction for inequalities?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, factorial

$2^n$ < $(n+1)!$

I'm not too familiar with how to do questions structured like these, as the examples I find online seem to randomly add things into the inequality to make is correct. The farthest I've gone is knowing the base case is right, substitution with k ($2^k$ < $(k+1)!$, and knowing I need to prove: $2^{k+1}$ < $(k+2)!$. Beyond this, I don't actually know what to do from here. Can someone help point me in the right direction? (it's for $n\geq 2$, and please don't give me the answer directly.)

EDIT: My idiot brain switched the inequality. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How do you get the left hand side of the statement you want to prove from your induction hypothesis?

Comment: You replace k with k+1 don't you?

Comment: The inequality looks backwards

Comment: Your $k$ is fixed, and you have to prove it for $k+1$. Do you realize that $2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, it is definitely backwards.

Comment: Crap you're right. Fixed

Comment: When you use induction, you need to connect the statement for $k$ with the statement for $k+1$, and that depends on the concrete statement. Would you agree that if you know that $2^k<\textrm{something}$, then $2^{k+1}<2\cdot\textrm{something}$?

Comment: Yes. That makes sense, but when would I use this?

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked, and answered, on this site many times. Please search for those earlier questions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/prove-by-induction-that-n2n and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/prove-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668193/prove-by-induction-n-ge-2n-1-for-any-n-ge-1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985979/show-that-n-%e2%89%a5-2n-1-is-true-by-induction-for-n-being-a-positive-integer and many, many more.

Comment: You know that $2^k<(k+1)!$. Therefore, $2^{k+1}<2\cdot(k+1)!$. It would be enough, by transitivity, to prove that $2\cdot(k+1)!<(k+2)!$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [factorial proof using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507140/factorial-proof-using-induction) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(n%2B1)!%5Cgt%202%5E%7Bn%7D%24&p=1). Note there are also many other similar questions, such as [Prove the inequality $n! \geq 2^n$ by induction](/q/76946) suggested by Henry above as a duplicate, the many ones listed in Gerry Myerson's comment, and a few other ones in that Approach0 search I mentioned.